# $this['key']->method() - what is this?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm practicing a little of PHP OO, I don't work actively with it, so I am sort of creating my own API to create websites. I'm a big fan of Laravel and I've been using it as reference to develop it and learn more of PHP and OO in the process, however now I've hit the wall.

I'm trying to build an Exception Handler in my "API" to handle 404 errors and such. I looked into Laravel and this is how you do it:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
});
```

So, it's using a callback, and I went to see what Laravel was doing with it, and here is the thing: I can't understand how this works.

The code can be found here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php

I'll just put what I was looking into:

```
/**
 * Register a 404 error handler.
 *
 * @param  \Closure  $callback
 * @return void
 */
public function missing(Closure $callback)
{
    $this->error(function(NotFoundHttpException $e) use ($callback)
    {
        return call_user_func($callback, $e);
    });
}
```

So far I can understand, but then there is the `$this->error(....);` so let's see that:

```
/**
 * Register an application error handler.
 *
 * @param  \Closure  $callback
 * @return void
 */
public function error(Closure $callback)
{
    $this['exception']->error($callback);
}
```

This I cannot understand. `$this` is an object, referencing itself, but it's referenced by an index, like in an array? And more, it's calling a method.

I'm sorry, but it's the first time I see this. How do you make the $this work as an array? And even further, call a method with it? I've been googling it around but I can't find a name for this, or what is it.

I believe, further in this class, there is something related to `$this['exception']->error($callback);`:

```
/**
 * Register the core class aliases in the container.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function registerCoreContainerAliases()
{
    $aliases = array(
        '...' => '...', // other stuff
        'exception'      => 'Illuminate\Contracts\Exception\Handler',
        '...' => '...', // other stuff  
    );

    foreach ($aliases as $key => $aliases)
    {
        foreach ((array) $aliases as $alias)
        {
            $this->alias($key, $alias);
        }
    }
}
```

But then, if I look at 'Illuminate\Contracts\Exception\Handler', it's just an interface. As far as I know, you implement an interface and then use the implementation, you don't call the interface directly. So that's kinda confusing too.

Link for the Handler class: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Exception/Handler.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php), `Application` extends [`Container`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php) which in turn implements [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php):

> Interface to provide accessing objects as arrays.

Instances of a class implementing this interface can be accessed as if they were arrays, which is what happens in `$this['exception']`.

Answer (score 3):

That is because [`Application`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/14665bc3c38c3ec24a12c904d013a663dc4a1d8f/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php) class in which you have found the confusing line is inherited from Container.

[`Container` class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/b70ccf2351a1f406a046dce7efcafc01327acb50/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php) implements [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface which is used to provide accessing objects as arrays.